# What is the 'official' server to client methode?

Tags: server, virtualbox, client

I know how to add a Windows 7 machine to a Windows Server 2008, which I also know that it needs a domain and I know how to create one. But, what I don't know, is how to get the same relationship between an Ubuntu server and an Ubuntu(Desktop)client?

I have made a Server and client in Virtualbox and am eager to learn.

**Additional Information**:

- Ubuntu Desktop: Ubuntu Trusty Tahr, 14.04
- Ubuntu Server: Ubuntu Trusty Tahr, 14.04

Comment: Well, what exactly do you want to achieve in this client-server configuration?  LDAP authentication?  Kerberos authentication?  Management of updates?  You're stating an INFINTELY broad question without any specifics of what you want the setup to achieve, and that's not conducive of a good question.  (Voting to close as too broad, in the question's current form)

Comment: WIll rephrase my question.

Comment: I never have used - nor do I have any knowledge - of the Ubuntu Server 'framework'? Thats why I'm asking this.

Comment: @adonis Not offended at all ;) Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 2):

Short answer:

There is no one default method.

---

Long answer:

Different services provided by the server for the client (for example, LDAP authentication) are individual bits of software, with their own protocols and communication requirements and setups.  There's no one 'method' for it.  And you have to configure each and every bit for use in your setup and network requirements.

It's not as simple as 'install microsoft server, connect windows 7 to the domain'.  It's a decision of what exactly you want to ***do*** with the setup, whether it's shared network storage, or the server having a set of users for authentication on the clients, or an email server for an internal office email system, etc.

(There is no way to answer this question in its current form because of the scope of the question, either, this is the best answer you'll get.)

Comment: As you're a reputation 9,479 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **>:-)**